# using a translation within a template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to use translation within another tag. for example:

```
{% if field.label_tag != {% trans "foo" %} %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

I know it's not possible to use tags inside eachother. So what's the best solution?

Comment: Check if blocktrans works for you:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag

Comment: @petkostas: I don't get your point, even If I want to use `blocktrans` I have to use it inside the `if` tag which is not possible.

Comment: {% blocktrans with foo="translatedfoodfromview" %}
{% if foo="something" %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endblocktrans %}

Comment: I am not sure if it would work with blocktrans but you can give it a try. Otherwise i would suggest moving the logic to somewhere else (form or model).

Comment: Sounds like a flaw in the template design.  Why would you want to base logic on what a word has been translated to?  Wouldn't it be more appropriate to base the logic on what language is being used, for example, and not that actual contents of the label?

Comment: @Casey Kingsy, I'm currently using translation in the form definition, so when I pass the form to the template, label tags are translated. The alternative solution is to pass the original labels to template and use the appropriate translation while rendering, which is not a good idea while the whole project uses translation in the form.

Comment: It's good to mention that the original problem is to render all fields of a regular form except one in the template, and I'm trying to do this checking the label_tag of the field.